# JNA passing reference of array into native DLL

Tags: java, jna

The function in the dll is:

```
int getInfo (
  unsigned int Index,
  unsigned int* Mask,
  unsigned int* Serial,
  unsigned __int64* licInfo);
```

It is important that `licInfo` is an array with 4 elements.

In Java the method is declared like this:

```
int getInfo(int Index, IntByReference Mask, IntByReference Serial, Memory licInfo);
```

the method call:

```
int Index = 0;
IntByReference Mask = null;
IntByReference Serial = null;
Memory LicInfo = new Memory(256);    
int status = dll.INSTANCE.getInfo(Index, Mask, Serial, licInfo);
```

The dll returns an error code that says the parameters are wrong. I am pretty sure the mistake is the last parameter. I also tried passing an long array directly or passing an Pointer without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function mapping itself looks sane, although I would replace `Memory` with `Pointer` in the mapping.  As `Memory` extends `Pointer` you can still initialize and pass the value as you do now.

Without the API documentation specifying what it expects for arguments, I must make some educated guesses as to the problem.  The native function expects an `int` and 3 pointers to information, the last of which you've stated is an array of `long`.  What is expected in the first two?

The problem is most likely the `null` values being passed for the `Mask` and `Serial` pointers.  Unless the API specifically says `null` is allowed there, these should most likely be initialized with `new IntByReference()` to allocate native-side memory for an `int` that can be populated on the native side.

While over-allocating memory for the `long[4]` shouldn't specifically cause the error, you've allocated 256 *bytes* for a 256 *bit* array.  Allocating `new Memory(32)` should suffice.